# How to AutoLock after AutoLogin

Tags: linux-mint, login, screen-lock, autologin

I configured AutoLogin on my Linux Mint Mate system because I am using it as a small home server for file sharing, etc. And some app don't work well if the user is not logged in. But I don't want the system to be unprotected, someone can access it if it logins automatically. So how to AutoLock immediately after AutoLogin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I was trying some commands on startup like:
mate-screensaver-command -l

but it was not working as mate-screensaver could not be running yet

So I tried:

```
mate-screensaver
sleep 1
mate-screensaver-command -l
```

but with no success either, so I discovered that the problem was that on starting the mate-screensaver, it was not returning until the process ended, and it would not happen.

So the final solution is to make a file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mate-screensaver&
sleep 1
/usr/bin/mate-screensaver-command -l
sleep 2
/usr/bin/mate-screensaver-command -l
sleep 3
/usr/bin/mate-screensaver-command -l
sleep 4
/usr/bin/mate-screensaver-command -l
```

I made the command 4 times just to be absolutely sure that it is going to lock because the command may fail if screensaver has not successfully started. There could be a more professional approach like checking if it has locked with mate-screensaver-command --query.

after saving the file, make it executable on its properties or chmod and put it on startup, (just type start on mate menu to find it), then disable the mate-screensaver entry on the startup apps as you are already starting it on this script.